# MySQL add special constraints between two tables

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to add a constraint between tables that would prevent a record from being deleted from table1 if it exists in table2, but table2 does not have to have an entry from table1.

Example: Table1 is sub_department information with an id field. Table2 is a department configuration table. Table2 has dept_id and sub_dept_id. Some configurations are only for the combination dept_id and sub_dept_id so a matching record must exist in the department table and sub-department table for corresponding id's. Since it is possible only the department has configuration information then sub_dept_id would default to zero. (not in the sub-department table). Because of this I can not add a normal constraint that would stop a sub_department from being removed if it is used in the configuration table.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, by using a foreign key constraint from table1 to table2

Comment: In case the foreign key doesn't cut it you can also use triggers.

Comment: If I add a constraint from table1 to table2 can records still be deleted from table2 while still in table1? I have not made any contraints like that. Thanks.